# ImportError: cannot import name get_ast_names error on lmfit

Tags: python, importerror, lmfit

I have recently updated to Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS. After that I tried to run some of my python codes and I got an error related to the [lmfit package](https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/), here's the code:

```
import scipy
from asteval import get_ast_names
import lmfit
```

(I have explicitly added the scipy and asteval modules to check python was finding them porperly)
I obtained this error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/maurizio/Documents/Python/Programmini/PhD/TEAS/Test.py", line 3, in <module>
    import lmfit
  File "/home/maurizio/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lmfit/__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
    from .confidence import conf_interval, conf_interval2d
  File "/home/maurizio/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lmfit/confidence.py", line 12, in <module>
    from .minimizer import MinimizerException
  File "/home/maurizio/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lmfit/minimizer.py", line 35, in <module>
    from .parameter import Parameter, Parameters
  File "/home/maurizio/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lmfit/parameter.py", line 8, in <module>
    from asteval import Interpreter, get_ast_names, valid_symbol_name
ImportError: cannot import name get_ast_names
```

which basically states that lmfit cannot find the function get_ast_names from asteval, although the python interpreter doesn't complain when I try to import it so it should be properly installed.
I have found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49905556/lmfit-package-importerror-cannot-import-name-differential-evolution) with a similar problem and the guy in the comments claims he solved it by reinstalling it with pip3, so I tried to compile it with python3 and there's no problem so the issue concerns only python 2

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you must have conflicting versions of `lmfit` and `asteval`.   This *should* have been automatically noticed (and ideally resolved) when installing `lmfit`, but something there appears to have gone wrong.  For the latest releases, you should get

```
>>> import asteval 
>>> asteval.__version__
0.9.12
>>> import lmfit
>>> lmfit.__version__
0.9.11
```

Depending on how you installed these, you may need to check for and remove older versions of `asteval` in your `$HOME/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/` folder and re-do `pip install asteval`.

Comment: Thank you, with your help I solved the problem! Basically deleted the folders and reinstalled asteval as you said, but that wasn't enough, so I deleted both asteval and lmfit  and reinstalled lmfit from scratch and that solved the problem!